# lapply r to one column of a csv file

Tags: r, lapply

I have a folder with several hundred `csv` files.  I want to use `lappply` to calculate the mean of one column within each csv file and save that value into a new csv file that would have two columns:  Column 1 would be the name of the original file.  Column 2 would be the mean value for the chosen field from the original file.  Here's what I have so far:

```
setwd("C:/~~~~")
list.files()
filenames <- list.files()
read_csv <- lapply(filenames, read.csv, header = TRUE)
dataset <- lapply(filenames[1], mean)
write.csv(dataset, file = "Expected_Value.csv")
```

Which gives the error message:

> Warning message: In mean.default("2pt.csv"[[1L]], ...) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

So I think I have 2(at least) problems that I cannot figure out.

First, why doesn't r recognize that column 1 is numeric? I double, triple checked the csv files and I'm sure this column is numeric.

Second, how do I get the output file to return two columns the way I described above?  I haven't gotten far with the second part yet.

I wanted to get the first part to work first. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: okay.  I'm running this on a test sample with just two files.  I ran `str` and `head` which confirmed that the column is numeric.  I don't understand your comment _but you still try to calculate the mean on the string filenames[1]..._  I guess maybe that's my problem.  I don't know how to specify a specific column in a csv file when using `lapply`.  the $, that I use when calculating mean on the column in one file is an invalid operator.  I read that I should use [] but I'm not sure if that is right for what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't use lapply but have done something similar. Hope this helps!

```
    i= 1:2 ##modify as per need

    ##create empty dataframe
    df <- NULL 

    ##list directory from where all files are to be read
    directory <- ("C:/mydir/")

    ##read all file names from directory
    x <- as.character(list.files(directory,,pattern='csv'))
    xpath <- paste(directory, x, sep="")

    ##For loop to read each file and save metric and file name 
    for(i in i) 
    {
    file <- read.csv(xpath[i], header=T, sep=",")
    first_col <- file[,1]
    d<-NULL
   d$mean <- mean(first_col)
   d$filename=x[i]
   df <- rbind(df,d)
    }

   ###write all output to csv
   write.csv(df, file = "C:/mydir/final.csv")

   CSV file looks like below 

    mean        filename
   1999.000661  hist_03082015.csv
   1999.035121  hist_03092015.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the two answers.  After much review, it turns out that there was a much easier way to accomplish my goal.  The `csv` files that I had were originally in one file.  I split them into multiple files by location.  At the time, I thought this was necessary to calculate `mean` on each type.  Clearly, that was a mistake.  I went to the original file and used `aggregate`. Code:

```
setwd("C:/~~")
allshots <- read.csv("All_Shots.csv", header=TRUE)
EV <- aggregate(allshots$points, list(Location = allshots$Loc), mean)
write.csv(EV, file= "EV_location.csv")
```

This was a simple solution.  Thanks again or the answers.  I'll need to get better at `lapply` for future projects so they were not a waste of time.